# Which of the concatenation options are the best to use?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I want to accomplish the following:

> string = TEST; cell reference = B2, value = ING; **RESULT = TESTING**

Which of the following options are the best to use?:

1. CONCAT: `=CONCAT("TEST",B2)`
2. & operator: `="TEST" & B2`
3. CONCATENATE: `=CONCATENATE("TEST", B2)`

Comment: "Best" in what way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CONCAT()` and `&` do the same thing, so in that case there isn't a difference between them (just personal preference I suppose)

CONCATENATE() *can* also be used to join 2 items, however it's typically used to join greater than 2 terms.

Which one is best? I'd say whichever option makes the formula the most readable, in this case I would say `CONCAT()` only because you can easily identify which function you're running, and the terms "TEST" and B2 are clearly defined as the arguments.

Comment: A clear and concise answer. That's exactly the answer I wanted Web Applications to have !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose:

```
="TEST"&B2
```

because I don't generally like typing any more than necessary.

And for sites like SO, SU and WA it can be one less language issue.