# How do I combine a cell value with a string in a Google Spreadsheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have the following `IF` condition in some cell:

```
=IF(A1>A2, "value is <C5>", "value is <D5>")
```

where `<C5>` and `<D5>` **should be** the values of cells `C5` and `D5`.

I know it is a simple question but searching was not successful. I don't really know how to phrase this.

Comment: How about just `=IF(A1>A2, C5, D5)`

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal text is mandatory. cannot be omitted. I need something like: `"value is %s, D5"`. don't know what the syntax is.

Comment: Ah, of course. See answer below (in a second).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the [string concatenation operator](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093592), `&`:

```
=IF(A1>A2, "value is " & C5, "value is " & D5)
```

This is equal to, but less verbose than:

```
=IF(A1>A2, CONCAT("value is ", C5), CONCAT("value is ", D5))
```

As to your follow-up comment, you can concatenate several strings and values:

```
=IF(A1>A2, "value is " & C5 & " right now, but could be " & D5, "value is " & D5 & " at the moment, but could be " & C5)
```

Also see [Combining stuff in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37505/combining-stuff-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: lovely. 10x a lot.

Comment: BDW, what if I have multiple cell values that I want to insert in different places in the text?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: The & is clutch. Thanks for putting both versions, I knew exactly what was happening.

Comment: That link for string concatenation doesn't mention anything about `&`. Please refer to the documentation for it. Great answer though.

Comment: @Rishav The link is for the `CONCAT` function, which, according to that link, is "equivalent to the `&` operator."

Comment: The `CONCAT` function is equivalent to `&` and works on non-string values as well, but only takes 2 arguments. The [`CONCATENATE` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123) takes 1 or more arguments and only works on strings.