# How can I append a string to a formula result?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I include the result of an equation followed by a piece of information in quotes? For instance if I had the code add numbers from three cells, and wanted to include the result followed by `lbs` to show the total weight?

I've tried a bunch of things like

```
=A1+A2+A3+"lbs"
=(A1+A2+A3+)"lbs"
=A1+A2+A3; "lbs"
=A1+A2+A3, "lbs"
```

Nothing is giving me anything besides parse errors and I haven't been able to find an answer browsing around.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses!

Ultimately what I found worked best for me was just & "lbs"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the below mentioned formulae, you can accomplish using double quotes.

### Formula 1

```
=SUM(A1:A3) & " ""lbs"""
```

### Formula 2

```
=CONCAT(SUM(A1:A3)," ""lbs""")
```

### Formula 3

```
=CONCATENATE(SUM(A1:A3)," ", """lbs""")
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[How can I append a string to a formula result?](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1awUN2Fi_dN3J9Vu88OH8ytXwslDyAiWLwkaMhCK_Cr4/edit?usp=sharing)**

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872008/1536038
- [Combining Stuff in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37505/29140)

Answer (score 1):

You might try pairs of single quotes inside double quotes:

```
# "''lbs''"
```

with or without the space.

Comment: that's cheating.....but nice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending `lbs` *to your formula*, you might get what you want by *formatting* the cell, using a custom format:

1. Select the cell containing the formula
2. From the *Format* menu, select *Number → More formats → Custom number format* [image: 'Custom Number Format' menu item]
3. In the dialog boks, enter `0.00 "lbs"` (note the quotes around `lbs`)[image: The custom format dialog]
4. Click *Apply*

The cell should now display the result of your formula, with `lbs` appended to it.
The format you just created can now be used on other cells as well. It is now listed directly under *Format → Number*:
[image: Custom formats listen on Format menu]

Using cell formats instead of appending a string to a formula has the advantage that you can now use the formula results in other formulas as well, without having to worry about the `lbs` characters.

See [the example spreadsheet I've set up](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15df2PE-_ewswhAsTpgdRTNTOE_ObP1GqW3mDL-FkXaM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Is it possible to add the double quotes as well?

Comment: Yes, it seems so, by escaping the double quotes: `0.00 \"lb\s\"`

Comment: However, I'm not sure the OP wants to _display_ the double quotes. As I read the question, he's trying to append `"lbs"` to the formula, so that it will output `lbs`. Perhaps you could clarify, @bryan-runyan?

Comment: Absolutely. I just suspected the OP wanted `lbs` displayed, and did not know about custom formats.

Answer (score 0):

The `to_text` and `Char` functions are what you need - like this:

Set `A5 = A1 + A2 + A3` and then use

```
=to_text(A5) & char(34) & "LBS" & char(34)
```

(It's good practise to keep your calculations and text-output of the results in separate formulae - it makes debugging easier.)

There's an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zndD-QNKyvMi_uHaG7Wc0VhPN42Bv2FDdMrAH8ZtJsw/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I was on my own till I found this sub. I found this worked also

```
=CONCAT("$", "" & (SUM(A1:A)))
```

New to this also, any comments/criticism is appreciated.